# Array data not passing from controller to view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I am writing a code in codeigniter trying to pass my user data from a controller to a view but the data is not passing and popping-up a error message, please help me out on this.

**controller**

```
public function customerRecive($cust_ID)
     {
          $ID_decript = base64_decode($cust_ID);
          $this->db->where('CustomerID', $ID_decript);
          $query=$this->db->get('gst_customermaster');
          $cust_details= $query->result_array();
          $data['cust_details'] = $cust_details;
          //print_r($cust_details);
          //load the department_view
          $this->load->view('category_link_details_view',$data);

     }
```

**view**

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th> # </th>
                  <th> CustomerCode</th>
                  <th> CustomerName</th>
                  <th> ContactPerson</th>
                  <!--<th> Edit</th>-->
                  <th> Delete</th>
                </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($cust_details); ++$i) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                     <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $cust_details[$i]->CustomerCode; ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $cust_details[$i]->CustomerName; ?></td>
                                     <td><?php echo $cust_details[$i]->ContactPerson; ?></td>
                                     <!-- <td><a href="#" onClick="show_confirm('edit',<?php $cust_details[$i]->id;?>)">Edit</a></td> -->

                                     <!-- <td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/<?php $cust_details[$i]->id;?>">Edit</a></td> -->
                                      <!--<td><?php echo anchor('Category_retrieve/edit_data/'.$cust_details[$i]->id, ' Edit');?></td> -->
                                      <td><?php echo anchor('Category_retrieve/delete_data/'.$cust_details[$i]->id, ' Delete');?></td>
                                </tr>

                           <?php } ?>


                  </tbody>
              </table>
```

Comment: Mind the use of MVC when using MVC frameworks. Queries inside models and not in the controller. And you could change the <?php echo ($i+1)?> to <?= $i++ ?> as a short version if you'd like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chage in controller.FEtch records in object formatusing `result()` instead of `result_array()`.Because you are using arrow operator for accessing members.

```
public function customerRecive($cust_ID)
     {
          $ID_decript = base64_decode($cust_ID);
          $this->db->where('CustomerID', $ID_decript);
          $query=$this->db->get('gst_customermaster');
          $cust_details= $query->result();//get result in object format
          $data['cust_details'] = $cust_details;
          //print_r($cust_details);
          //load the department_view
          $this->load->view('category_link_details_view',$data);

     }
```

For more see docs https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy..!